# Populate a GridView with 3 Lists

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have 3 lists and i would like them to populate a gridview when the button is clicked.

In Layout.xml the griView has `numColumns` of 3

```
private List<Strings> list1;
private List<Strings> list2;
private List<Strings> list3;

public void buttonOnClick(View v)
{
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
           android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list1);

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I want the GridView to print like this

```
list1(0)   list2(0)    list3(0)
list1(1)   list2(1)    list3(1)
list1(2)   list2(2)    list3(2)
list1(3)   list2(3)    list3(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Suposing your three lists are the same size:

```
List<String> gridList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i<list1.length; i++) {
    gridList.add(list1.get(i));
    gridList.add(list2.get(i));
    gridList.add(list3.get(i));
}

// Creates adapter with mixed list.
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, gridList);
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then set your gridView numColumns to 3:

```
<GridView android:id="@+id/gvItems" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case, make a fourth list, that contains the contents of your three lists in a kind of "interlaced" manner:

```
{ l1[0], l2[0], l3[0],   // just a sample array for
  l1[1], l2[1], l3[1] }; // illustrational purposes
```

And feed your `ArrayAdapter` with a such created `ArrayList`.
Be aware, however, to keep the numbers of columns fixed, otherwise your `GridView` will not look as intended anymore.